# How to have a trait handling strings and list?

Tags: scala

I want to have a trait that would work for both `String` and `List[_]`. That is:

```
trait Mixer[A] {
  def mix(a: A, b: A): A = b ++ a ++ b
  def isMix(abab: A, b: A) =
    abab.endsWith(b) && abab.startsWith(b) && abab.length > 2*b.length
}

object MixerString extends Mixer[String]
object MixerListInt extends Mixer[List[Int]]
```

**Failed attempt**

```
trait Mixer[C, A] {
  implicit def toSeqLike(in: A): collection.SeqLike[C, A]
  implicit val bf: collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[A, C, A]
  def mix(a: A, b: A): A = b ++ a ++ b
  def isMix(abab: A, b: A) =
    abab.endsWith(b) && abab.startsWith(b) && abab.length > 2*b.length
}
```

It complains on the method `isMix` with:

> error: type mismatch;
>   `found   : A`
>   `required: scala.collection.GenSeq[?]`
>   `>              abab.endsWith(b) && abab.startsWith(b) && abab.length > b.length`
>   `>                            ^`

**Question**

Either how do I solve this last error, or how can I do something simpler?

**Edit: complete solution (thanks @Frederico)**

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.SeqLike
trait Mixer[C, A] {
  implicit def toSeqLike(in: A): SeqLike[C, A]
  implicit val bf: CanBuildFrom[A, C, A]
  def mix(a: A, b: A): A = b ++ a ++ b
  def isMix(abab: A, b: A) =
    abab.endsWith(b.seq) && abab.startsWith(b.seq) && abab.length > 2*b.length
}

object MixerString extends Mixer[Char, String] {
  val bf = implicitly[CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]]
  def toSeqLike(in: String): SeqLike[Char,String] = in
}
object MixerListInt extends Mixer[Int, List[Int]] {
  val bf = implicitly[CanBuildFrom[List[Int],Int,List[Int]]]
  def toSeqLike(in: List[Int]): SeqLike[Int,List[Int]] = in
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer, you have to use [`.seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html#seq:Seq[A]) like `abab.endsWith(b.seq)` and `abab.startsWith(b.seq)`.